# Insertion to table fails with FMDB

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, fmdb

I am trying to insert some values in my database in AppDelegate in Application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions however each time it fails to insert data.

**code**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
[database open];
FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:@"select * from settings"];
if(results == nil)
{
 NSLog(@"Creating DB");
 [database beginTransaction];
 [database executeUpdate:@"create table settings(id int primary key, defaultaction text, beepsound text, vibrateeffect text, level text)"];
 NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into settings(id,defaultaction,beepsound,vibrateeffect,level) values (%d, '%@', '%@','%@','%@',)",11,@"auto", @"YES", @"YES", @"HIGH"];
 NSLog(@" %@",path);
 BOOL y= [database executeUpdate:query];
 if (!y)
 {
 NSLog(@"insert failed!!");
 }

 [database commit];
 [database close];


 }
```

Comment: Doesn't that API provide you with any error messages?  If not then you should stop using it, as it's crap.  If it does, then retrieve them and report them.

Comment: @trojanfoe...I have been using this from very long time and it was working pretty good. Today morning I found this type of issue. I am not able to understand what to do...

Comment: Like I said, retrieve the error message and it will give you a clue.  Without this error message no one can help you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem is in your code of insert query

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into settings(id,defaultaction,beepsound,vibrateeffect,level) values (%d, '%@', '%@','%@','%@',)",11,@"auto", @"YES", @"YES", @"HIGH"];
```

You have added one more , at last in values() check and remove last , it will definitely work

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into settings(id,defaultaction,beepsound,vibrateeffect,level) values (%d, '%@', '%@','%@','%@')",11,@"auto", @"YES", @"YES", @"HIGH"];
```

try this query

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *query = @"INSERT into settings(id,defaultaction,beepsound,vibrateeffect,level) 
VALUES (%@, %@, %@,%@,%@)";

BOOL y = [database executeUpdate:query, [NSNumber numberWithInt:11],@"auto", @"YES", @"YES", @"HIGH"];
```

Try changing your query to the above stated query, it will work for sure if the table was created successfully.

Good luck.